# dynamic data web scraping selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

Trying to get the load data from sldc website. Below is the python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.punjabsldc.org/realtimepbGen.aspx")
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("table")
print(element.text)
driver.close()
```

I need to fetch the value of all the running plants load in one go. I tried various methods but only thing I'm getting is the plant names instead of generation load data.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is an "sldc website"? What are you trying to accomplish? What is the "load data"?

Comment: sldc stands for state load dispatch center and if you go on the link provided in the code then there is a table which shows power plant load and i want to extract that value which i m unable to get.

Comment: Where is the HTml? Is there any error?What you code tried so far?

Comment: i tried various 'find element by' methods. i didn't get required output.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.punjabsldc.org/realtimepbGen.aspx")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loadMW"]')
print(element.text)
driver.close()
```

Comment: it returned nothing. i just checked it